# Select count of column grouped by another column SQL

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have two tables, one called Products and one called Products_Category. I want to show the inventory count for each category (grouped by category), and also display the name of the category. The Products table has the inventory count for each Product, but the Products_Category table has the Category names. How can I display the two together? Should I be using some kind of join?

Here's what I'm trying to get:

Category_Name --------- Sum(Products_Inventory)

------Books --------------------  1  ----------
------Toys----------------------  2  ----------

But as of right now all I'm able to display is the category *ID* instead of the category *name*, like so:

------- 1 ------------------------ 1 ----------
------- 2 ------------------------ 2 ----------

Comment: I recommend including a link to sqlfiddle.com with your DDL and some sample data all setup, so that people can give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT PC.Category_Name, Sum(P.Products_Inventory)
FROM Products_Category PC
   INNER JOIN Products P ON PC.ProductId = P.ProductId
GROUP BY PC.Category_Name
```

BTW -- This assumes you have a ProductId field in each table.  And if I could make a suggestion, you should probably have a Category table as well (better for normalization).  Store your ProductId and CateogryId in your Products_Category table.

Good luck.

Comment: What is meant by Products_Category *PC* and Products *P*?

Comment: Those are aliases on the tables -- shorthand for not having to type the entire name.  Make sense?

Comment: I think so, I was just confused on how you wrote Products and then wrote P, and wrote Products_Category followed by another PC

Comment: Makes life easier, especially on long table names.  Table aliasing :)

Answer (score 0):

For these queries I assume `product_id` is on both tables (you'll have to use the correct field name if I guessed wrong). I'm also using `Product_Category.description` as the name of the field that has the category names.

This query will get you all categories, and a count of 0 for any product category that's **not** found in the `Product` table.

If `Product` contains one record for each *product* in stock (ie, 4 books would mean 4 `Product` records), than `COUNT()` is the function you want.

```
SELECT Products_Category.description, COUNT(Product.product_id) AS category_count
FROM Products_Category
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Products ON Products_Category.product_id=Products.product_id
GROUP BY Products_Category.description
```

If `Product` contains one record for each *type* product in stock (ie, 4 books would mean 1 record with a `product_count` of 4), than `SUM()` is the function you want.

```
SELECT Products_Category.description, SUM(Product.product_count) AS category_count
FROM Products_Category
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Products ON Products_Category.product_id=Products.product_id
GROUP BY Products_Category.description
```

If you only want records returned when you have inventory in that category, change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Products_Category.description, SUM(Product.product_count) AS category_count
FROM Products_Category
   INNER JOIN Products ON Products_Category.product_id=Products.product_id
GROUP BY Products_Category.description
```

Answer (score 0):

the most simplest way is to do this..

SELECT a.Category_Name, Sum(b.Products_Inventory)
FROM Products_Category a, Products b  
Where a.ProductId = b.ProductId
GROUP BY a.Category_Name

hope it helps